# liquibase: can I rollback a drop table by referring to a prior changeset id?

Tags: liquibase, rollback

I have introduced a changeset `<dropTable table_name="foo">` that will get rid of the no longer needed table *foo*.
Since `dropTable` has no auto-rollback I can of course specify the rollback actions manually (by copying the contents of the changeset that originally created *foo*). It would however be more convenient and less error-prone to just re-apply the said changeset - is this possible?

Update: it is possible, the answer is hidden in the [Liquibase Auto Rollback](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/liquibase-auto-rollback.html) subpage of [using-rollback](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/using-rollback.html) which does not only list change types and their auto-rollback capability but also has an example of referring to an older `changeSetId`.

However, this feature seems not to be the most powerful: if the changeset in question is stored in another file (we have all minor versions in separate files which are put together by `"include file=..." tags`) the changeset is not found.
Plus it's only possible to specify one changeset, so if the table in question has been created using multiple change sets (e.g. adding foreign keys in an extra step) specifying just one set to apply will not get us to the original DB setup.

Answer (score 0):

That is an interesting question. 2 conditions have to be met in order to re-apply the changesets

1. Have a changeste with runAlways attribute (Examplel can be found here: https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changeset.html?Highlight=runalways)
2. Have a precondition that is evaluated prior to running the changeset.- https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/preconditions.html?Highlight=pre%20condition